# HTML Tittle attribute showing only First Word

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I using title attribute in jQuery.

```
createAlert: function () {            
  return '<img id="img" class="img pull-left" src="/Content/img/demo_16px.png" tabindex="0" style="outline: none;" title=' + demo.rawData + '></span>';
}
```

Here In this code, title contain dynamic data(**demo.rawData Contain text = 'This is my code')**

But when I hover in a browser for title it only displaying **This**(i.e only first word)

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong.?

Comment: Add quotes around your attribute value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to surround the title in "" like so `title="' + demo.rawData + '"` rather than `title=' + demo.rawData + '` otherwise the rendered HTML will be invalid

```
createAlert: function () {            
  return '<img id="img" class="img pull-left" src="/Content/img/demo_16px.png" tabindex="0" style="outline: none;" title="' + demo.rawData + '"></span>';
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you go with one more solution using `ES6 template literal`

```
createAlert: function () {            
  return `<img id="img" class="img pull-left" src="/Content/img/demo_16px.png" tabindex="0" style="outline: none;" title="${demo.rawData}"></span>`;
}
```

Reference Document: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals